# console application main thread is not in main loop using pysimplegui

Tags: python, multithreading, pysimplegui

For few days now, I have been researching on how to fix this issue. Basically I have a console application where in certain stages, I call pysimplegui to create a notification window or:

1. main console program that needs to always work on the background
2. if capture I.e a keystroke, create an alert window. On this stage, I need the main console program to still be capturing keystroke while a pysimplegui window is created. Hence why I am using a thread to open the pysimplegui window in a new thread.

How I have developed my program.

```
if (threading.active_count() < 2):
    wt = threading.Thread(target=createwindow, name="noty", args=(argumnets,),
                                          daemon=True)
    wt.setDaemon(True) # just to be safe
    wt.start()
    wt.join()
```

create window:

```
def createalertwindow(Attack):
    # I have removed this part of the code where I design the gui window just to make easy to understand
    e, v = win.read(timeout=5000)
    if (e == "e"):
        print("e button clicked")
    elif (e == "Ok"):
        win.close()
    # close first window
    win.close()
```

Now Every time I run above code I get below exception errors:

> Exception ignored in: <function Variable.**del** at 0x000001EACB37CCA0>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Abdul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 350, in **del**
> if self._tk.getboolean(self._tk.call("info", "exists", self.*name)):
> RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
> Exception ignored in: <function Variable.**del** at 0x000001EACB37CCA0>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Abdul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter_*init**.py", line 350, in **del**
> if self._tk.getboolean(self._tk.call("info", "exists", self._name)):
> RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop

I read many question already out there, but found none that could fix the issue for me I.e I tried using:

```
plt.switch_backend('agg')

wt = threading.Thread(target=createwindow, name="noty", args=(argumnets,),
                                          daemon=True)
wt.setDaemon(True)
...
```

I may be note worthy to mention again that my main program is a console application not a gui application.

I am using threading library for threading but am okay to switch if I have better options and am using pysimplegui for create gui windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you cannot call PySimpleGUI/tkinter in another thread.
Here, try to set main program as one thread and called in PySimpleGUI/tkinter.
The same, remember that don't call PySimpleGUI directly in your main_program and use method `window.write_event_value` to generate an event, then do it in your event loop.

Example code,

```py
from time import sleep
import threading
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def hello():
    layout = [[sg.Text("Hello, my friend !")]]
    window = sg.Window("Hello", layout, keep_on_top=True, modal=True)
    window.read(timeout=1000, close=True)

def main_program():
    count = 5
    while count > 0:
        window.write_event_value("Hello", None)
        sleep(3)
        count -=1
    window.write_event_value(sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, None)

layout = [[]]

window = sg.Window("Title", layout, alpha_channel=0, finalize=True)
threading.Thread(target=main_program, daemon=True).start()
while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == "Hello":
        hello()

window.close()
```