# PySimpleGui is Not Responding when other program runs

Tags: python, pysimplegui

Trying to create a program that watches a website for videos and plays them at random along with checking when they are done to play the next video.

Currently using pysimplegui as an interface and it runs just fine until it loads a program which plays the videos saved in a txt file as URLs.

As the videos are playing it runs just fine but pysimplegui window is not responding.

```
def main():
    window1, window2, window3 = mainMenu(),None, None # start off with mainMenu opened first

    while True:
        window, event, values = sg.read_all_windows()
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == '-EXIT-':
            window.close()
            if window == window2:
                window2 = None
            elif window == window3:
                window3 = None
            elif window == window1:
                break
        """
        Change Screen to Set Weekly Reset window
        """
        if event == '-RESET-':
            window2 = weeklyReset()

        """
        Button press is passed to dayOfReset.txt
        """
        if event == 'Sunday':
            weeklySchedule.setDayOfReset('Sunday')
        elif event == 'Monday':
            weeklySchedule.setDayOfReset('Monday')
        elif event == 'Tuesday':
            weeklySchedule.setDayOfReset('Tuesday')
        elif event == 'Wednesday':
            weeklySchedule.setDayOfReset('Wednesday')
        elif event == 'Thursday':
            weeklySchedule.setDayOfReset('Thursday')
        elif event == 'Friday':
            weeklySchedule.setDayOfReset('Friday')
        elif event == 'Saturday':
            weeklySchedule.setDayOfReset('Saturday')
        # ------------------------------------------ #
        """
        Change Screen to Settings window
        """
        if event == '-SETTINGS-' and not window2 or window3:
            window3 = settings()
        # ------------------------------------------ #

        # WEEKLY SCHEDUAL OPTION
        if event == '-WEEKLY-':
            daysOfWeek = weeklySchedule.get_dayOfWeek()
            weeklySchedule.play_video(daysOfWeek)

        # DUBBED ANIME OPTION
        elif event == '-DUBBED-':
            print("THIS IS DUB ONLY")
            url = "https://www.wcofun.com/dubbed-anime-list"
            numOfShows = 3
            schedule = typeChoice.choiceSchedule(url, numOfShows)
            typeChoice.play_video(schedule)

        # SUBBED ANIME OPTION
        elif event == '-SUBBED-':
            print("THIS IS SUB ONLY")
            url = "https://www.wcofun.com/subbed-anime-list"
            numOfShows = 3
            schedule = typeChoice.choiceSchedule(url, numOfShows)
            typeChoice.play_video(schedule)

        # ANIMATED CARTOONS
        elif event == '-OTHER-':
            print("THIS IS OTHER CARTOONS")
            url = "https://www.wcofun.com/cartoon-list"
            numOfShows = 3
            schedule = typeChoice.choiceSchedule(url, numOfShows)
            typeChoice.play_video(schedule)

        # MOVIE OPTION
        elif event == '-MOVIE-':
            print("THIS IS MOVIES")
            url = "https://www.wcofun.com/movie-list"
            schedule = movieChoice.choice_movie_schedule(url)
            movieChoice.play_video(schedule)

        # Close the program
        elif event == '-CLOSE-':
            quit()


    window.close()

        # if event == '-SETTINGS-':
        #     print('this is settings')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have tried doing multithreading but I do not think it's working or I am not using it in the right location.

I am not for sure what else to try to make the gui run along side the program.

Comment: Do your long job by multithreading, like call `threading.Thread(target=movieChoice.play_video, args=(schedule,), daemon=True).start()` or `window.perform_long_operation(lambda schedule=schedule:movieChoice.play_video(schedule), 'Done')`.

Comment: The Gui is still not responding even though I do this. 
daysOfWeek = weeklySchedule.get_dayOfWeek()
            threading.Thread(target=weeklySchedule.play_video(daysOfWeek), args=(daysOfWeek), daemon=True).start()

The part that's in the thread is the main thing that runs the huge program

Comment: Wrong code for `Thread(target=weeklySchedule.play_video(daysOfWeek), args=(daysOfWeek), daemon=True).start()` where target should be a function, not result of your function, and args is a tuple, not `(daysOfWeek)`. Try `Thread(target=weeklySchedule.play_video, args=(daysOfWeek, ), daemon=True).start()`. There should be no any GUI call in your function, excpet for `window.write_event_value`.

Comment: Maye you can refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75835160/11936135